# ConfirmEmailAsync() method is not working

Tags: email, asp.net-identity-2, confirm

I am having issue in confirming new user email. the Confirm email link works for first 20 minutes , but after 50 minutes the link expires. I have set the token expiration time to 24 hours. Please help me in resolving this issue. I am stuck on it for last 2 days:(.My code is as follows:
I am setting the token lifetime in Create() method in ApplicationUserManager as following:

```
       var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;

        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
            {
                TokenLifespan = _settings.ConfirmationAndResetTokenExpirationTimeSpan
            };
        }
```

And then In AccountsController, the Create method for new user is geiven below. The SendEmailAsync method consist of email subject, email body, generated password and the callback uri.

```
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.Bam.Name.Admin)]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(Routes.Accounts.Template.Create, Name = Routes.Accounts.Name.Create)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(CreateUserBindingModel createUserBindingModel)
    {
        IHttpActionResult result;


            var memberNameExists = UserManager.Users.Any(x => x.MemberName.ToLower() == createUserBindingModel.MemberName.ToLower());

            if (!memberNameExists)
            {
                var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = createUserBindingModel.Email,
                    Email = createUserBindingModel.Email,
                    FirstName = createUserBindingModel.FirstName,
                    LastName = createUserBindingModel.LastName,
                    Company = createUserBindingModel.Company,
                    Location = createUserBindingModel.Location,
                    PhoneNumber = createUserBindingModel.PhoneNumber,
                    MemberName = createUserBindingModel.MemberName,
                    LastLoginDate = SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value,
                    CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                    UpdateDate = DateTime.Now,
                    UpdatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = createUserBindingModel.TwoFactorEnabled,
                    SecurityResetRequired = true,
                    PasswordExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PasswordExpirationDays"]))
                };

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(createUserBindingModel.AvatarBase64))
                {
                    var avatarBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(createUserBindingModel.AvatarBase64);
                    var resizedAvatarBytes = ImageResizer.ResizeImage(avatarBytes, _avatarWidth, _avatarHeight);

                    applicationUser.UserAvatar = new ApplicationUserAvatar
                    {
                        Avatar = resizedAvatarBytes
                    };
                }

                var generatedPassword = PasswordGenerator.GenerateStrongPassword(10, 10);

                var identityResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, generatedPassword);

                if (identityResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(applicationUser.Id, createUserBindingModel.Roles.ToArray());

                    var token = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(applicationUser.Id);
                    var callbackUri = string.Format("{0}?userId={1}&token={2}", createUserBindingModel.EmailConfirmationCallbackUri, applicationUser.Id, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token));

                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(applicationUser.Id, Email.Confirmation.Subject, string.Format(Email.Confirmation.Body, string.Format("{0} {1}", applicationUser.FirstName, applicationUser.LastName), callbackUri, generatedPassword, _settings.AccessTokenExpirationTimeSpan.TotalHours));

                    var userUrl = new Uri(Url.Link(Routes.Accounts.Name.Get, new { id = applicationUser.Id }));
                    var roles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(applicationUser.Id);
                    var contract = _accountsMapper.ToContract(applicationUser, roles);

                    result = Created(userUrl, contract);
                }
                else
                {
                   result = GetErrorResult(identityResult);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Member Name already exists!");

                result = BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Once the email is generated the UI has following JS angular code which gets executed and the provide the userid and token to service.
Angular JS code:

```
angular.module('confirmEmailModule').factory('confirmEmailFactory', function ($http) {
var factory = {};

factory.confirmEmail = function(userId, token) {

    var encodedToken = encodeURIComponent(token);
    var uri = '/identity/api/accounts/confirmemail?userId=' + userId + '&token=' + token;

    return $http.post(uri);
}

return factory;
```

});

and the Service is :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(Routes.Accounts.Template.ConfirmEmail, Name = Routes.Accounts.Name.ConfirmEmail)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConfirmEmail([FromUri] string userId, [FromUri] string token)
    {
        //var decodedToken = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token);
        var identityResult = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, token);
        var result = identityResult.Succeeded ? StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent) : GetErrorResult(identityResult);

        return result;
    }
```

Please advice.

Comment: What's your error when you are debugging, next try to send simple email without expiration link then go for it.

Comment: I am getting error "Invalid Token"

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this issue. I am posting it if somebody faced the same issue. In my case the services and web API were on different servers. Different machine keys caused this issue. So I generated the machine key for my Web application and posted the same machine key in web.config file of Identity service. After that it worked. For more information on generating machine key, following link is helpful.
http://gunaatita.com/Blog/How-to-Generate-Machine-Key-using-IIS/1058

Comment: Thanks, Adding the same machine key in web.config file fixed our problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. Hope it helps out;

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string token)
{
    if (userId == null || token == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("employees", "home");
    }

    var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"The User ID {userId} is invalid";
        return View("NotFound");
    }

    var result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, Uri.EscapeDataString(token));
    if (result != null)
    {
        user.EmailConfirmed = true;
        await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        return View();
    }
}
```